# Adding background colour/shape that runs out of the container tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap4 and was just curious if its possible to add a background colour/shape to a header tag that runs out of the container class. For example I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
        <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        <h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
        <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Test Text</h3>
        <hr style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350">
        <hr style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350">
    </div>
</div>
```

Which currently looks something like this:

[image]

How would I go about adding a background colour and shape to achieve the below effect:

[image]

I have tried simple background colour changes and have tried Googling this but wasn't really sure what I was looking for and couldn't find much. Any point in the right direction or help would be amazing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.page {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
}
h1::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -99999px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

</p>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

</p>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

It is impossible to make any background out of container.

You may try to play with pseudo-elements and positions. For example, each heading will have ::after element, with 'absolute' posotion and left: -9999px and set background color for ::after element, not the heading.

Answer (score 0):

you can use clip-path: polygon property, here is an example, but your code is not edited, so you should edit and play with the polygon properties to achieve your goal. here is a site where you can test them, https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

here is an example for your code:

```css
.shape {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 83% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                    <h2 class="shape">Why do we use it?</h2>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
                    <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
                    <h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
                    <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
                    <h2></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>Test Text</h3>
                    <hr style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350">
                    <hr style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350">
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

At the end it looks like this with your code:
[image]